# The most elegant solution using Lua tables to this snippet of Python

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm learning Lua and coming from Python Lua tables seem rather convoluted, the simple example below is so elegant but translating this into Lua is difficult for me, as Lua has no concept of tuples.

So I'm looking for the best Lua solution for this snippet

```
a = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
if (3, 3) in a:
    print("Yay!")
else:
    print("Nay!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pair is just like length-2 list, so you could express `a` simply as

```
a = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}
```

The tricky part here is rather that Python's `in` compares objects by their *value* rather than their *identity*. That is, in Python, `(1,2) in [(1,2)]` but `(1,2) is not (1,2)`.

Lua has no notion of "value" equality (except for strings and numbers, which don't have identities).

You could override the behavior of `==` by setting the `__eq` metametod. Unfortunately, Lua doesn't have a function for searching a table for a value equal to some query, so it might be overkill.

Directly, you could write a "contains pair" function that works on the `a` as defined above like this:

```
function containsPair(list, pair)
    -- Find a key of list with a value equal to `pair` (as a pair)
    for k, v in ipairs(list) do
        if v[1] == pair[1] and v[2] == pair[2] then
            return k
        end
    end
end

if containsPair(a, {3, 3}) then
    ......
end
```

You could make it more general by passing a function do the comparison (or equivalently, just use `==` but implement the `__eq` metamethod):

```
function containsLike(list, lhs, eq)
    -- Find a key of list with a value equal to lhs
    for k, lhs in ipairs(list) do
        if eq(lhs, rhs) then
            return k
        end
    end
end

function pairEq(a, b)
    return a[1] == b[1] and a[2] == b[2]
end

if containsLike(list, {3, 3}, pairEq) then
    ......
end
```

---

If what you're really after is a *set of pairs*, you could instead use a "two-dimensional map" (a map of maps):

```
a = {}
a[1] = {}
a[1][1] = true
a[2] = {}
a[2][2] = true
a[3] = {}
a[3][3] = true

if a[3] and a[3][3] then
    ......
end
```

Checking that rows have already been created could be cumbersome. You can use metatables to imitate Python's `defaultdict` and clean this up:

```
function default(f)
    return setmetatable({}, {
        __index = function(self, k)
            -- self[k] is nil, but was asked for.
            -- Let's assign it to the default value:
            self[k] = f()

            -- and return the new assignment:
            return self[k]
        end,
    })
end

local a = default(function() return {} end)
a[1][1] = true
a[2][2] = true
a[3][3] = true

if a[3][3] then
    ......
end
```

Comment: A caveat: "The order in which the indices are enumerated is not specified, even for numeric indices." (https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-next); this means that `ipairs` needs to be replaced with numerical `for` loop.

Comment: `ipairs` is unrelated to `next`, it does guarantee the order https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-ipairs , https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lbaselib.c.html#ipairsaux . Not that the order of set traversal would be important in the task at hand.

Comment: The first example was just what I was looking for, thank you. I have implemented a similar function into my code